# Find differences between two Python objects

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way in Python to find the differences between two objects of the same type, or between two objects of any type?  By differences I mean the value of one of their properties is different, or one object has a property that the other doesn't.  So for example:

```
dog.kingdom = 'mammal'
dog.sound = 'bark'

cat.kingdom = 'mammal'
cat.sound = 'meow'
cat.attitude = 'bow to me'
```

In this example, I'd want to know that the `sound` property is different, and the `attitude` property is only in `cat`.

The use case for this is I'm trying to override some default behavior in a library, and I'm setting up an object different than the library is but I don't know what.

Comment: [deepdiff](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/deepdiff)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
print(dog.__dict__.items() ^ cat.__dict__.items())
```

Result:

```
{('attitude', 'bow to me'), ('sound', 'meow'), ('sound', 'bark')}
```

For set-like objects, `^` is the symmetric difference.

Comment: See docs for [more set operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set).

Comment: Note that, for this to work, all attributes must be [hashable](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__hash__#object.__hash__).

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at [DeepDiff](https://pypi.org/project/deepdiff/).

Between two instances of the same class :

```py
from deepdiff import DeepDiff
from pprint import pprint

class Animal:
    pass

dog = Animal()
cat = Animal()

dog.kingdom = 'mammal'
dog.sound = 'bark'

cat.kingdom = 'mammal'
cat.sound = 'meow'
cat.attitude = 'bow to me'

differences = DeepDiff(dog, cat)
pprint(differences)
>> {'attribute_added': [root.attitude],
>>  'values_changed': {'root.sound': {'new_value': 'meow', 'old_value': 'bark'}}}
```

Between two instances of different classes :

```py
from deepdiff import DeepDiff
from pprint import pprint

class Dog:
    pass

class Cat:
    pass

dog = Dog()
cat = Cat()


dog.kingdom = 'mammal'
dog.sound = 'bark'

cat.kingdom = 'mammal'
cat.sound = 'meow'
cat.attitude = 'bow to me'

differences = DeepDiff(dog, cat, ignore_type_in_groups=(Dog, Cat))
pprint(differences)
>> {'attribute_added': [root.attitude],
>>  'values_changed': {'root.sound': {'new_value': 'meow', 'old_value': 'bark'}}}
```